# scikit-learn: building a learning curve with SVC

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm trying to graph a learning curve using the SVC classifier. The dataset is kinda skewed, about 150, 1000, 1000, 1000 and 150 in size. I'm running into problem with fitting the estimator:

```
  File "/Users/carrier24sg/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/learning_curve.py", line 135, in learning_curve
    for train, test in cv for n_train_samples in train_sizes_abs)
  File "/Users/carrier24sg/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 644, in __call__
    self.dispatch(function, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/carrier24sg/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 391, in dispatch
    job = ImmediateApply(func, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/carrier24sg/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 129, in __init__
    self.results = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/carrier24sg/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1233, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/Users/carrier24sg/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 140, in fit
    X = atleast2d_or_csr(X, dtype=np.float64, order='C')
  File "/Users/carrier24sg/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 450, in _validate_targets
    % len(cls))
ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1
```

My code

```
  df = pd.read_csv('../resources/problem2_processed_validate.csv')
  data, label = preprocess_text(df)

  cv = StratifiedKFold(label, 10)
  plt = plot_learning_curve(estimator=SVC(), title="Learning curve", X=data, y=label.values, cv
  train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
    estimator, data, y=label, cv=cv, train_sizes=np.linspace(.1, 1.0, 5))
```

Even though I use stratified sampling, I still run into this error. I believe its because the learning curve code doesn't perform stratification when incrementing dataset size, and I've got all similar class labels at one step.

How should I resolve this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `StratifiedShuffleSplit` instead of `StratifiedKFold`, and then write the learning curve loop yourself, creating a new CV object at each iteration. `StratifiedShuffleSplit` allows you to specify a `train_size` and a `test_size` which you can increment as you create your learning curve. As long as you let `train_size` be greater than the number of classes, it will be able to stratify.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. `learning_curve` doesn't perform stratification when creating a smaller data set, it just takes the first bit of the data. Lines 134-136 in `learning_curve.py` say

```
train[:n_train_samples] for n_train_samples in train_sizes_abs
```

You can shuffle your data in advance, so that the slice `train[:n_train_samples]` may (but is not guaranteed to) include data points from all classes. If you are willing to do some more work, what @eickenberg proposed will work.

PS This sounds like something that should be included in `sklearn`. If you do end up writing that code, please send a pull request on github